# What's causing Brut.Androlib.AndrolibException error when trying to decompile an apk using Apktool.jar in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, apktool

error apktool  error: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.directory.DirectoryException: file must be a directory

I was trying Decompiler apk
In my app. I include Apktool.jar in the lib file. But it gives me an error. I tried a lot but it didn't work. I need help please

kotlin

```
package com.lamineml.apktool

import android.os.Bundle

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

import brut.androlib.ApkDecoder
import brut.androlib.ApktoolProperties
import brut.apktool.Main
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       
            try{

                Main.main(arrayOf("d","/sdcard/m/m.apk"))
                
            }catch (e:Exception){
                println("error: $e")
               


            }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the whole stack trace. Disclaimer: I'm the original author of apktool, however, I don't maintain it for years.

Comment: Depending on the used Android version your posted code can not work as apps don't have write access to `/sdcard/m` better use the app specific external directory below `/sdcard/Android/...`